# Where is my eth0 configuration on Wheezy

Tags: networking, debian

I have a perfectly happy Debian Wheezy 7.4 install that sets up `eth0` as DHCP.  But as I want to set a static IP address for it, I navigate to `/etc/network` and open up the `interfaces` file and see the entire contents:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

But .. but .. but where is `eth0` being configured?

Using the graphical system tools I can set a static IP, but I'd prefer to do this via the command line.  But where do I do this?

Comment: @Qasim You should make that an answer and not a comment to my question

Comment: sorry i have my answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the ip in `/etc/network/interfaces`. It's not showing because it seems that you are using network-manager.

My `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

It's because I am also using network-manager. You can also check the following link for network settings.

[How to set static ip in debian](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)

Note : Settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` will bypass network-manager.

Comment: I didn't *know* I was using Network Manager.  Thanks for that.